# Indented select case statments for grade app

Tags: vb.net, switch-statement

```
Select Case form_Login.FF_CorLev_CMB.SelectedIndex
                Case 1
                Case "U"
                    grade_Score = sub_Grade < 420
                    MsgBox("Not enough points")
                Case "P"
                    grade_Score = sub_Grade >= 420 < 460
                    form_Cert.TF_usrGrade_Text.Text = "P"
                Case "M"
                    grade_Score = sub_Grade > 460 < 500
                    form_Cert.TF_usrGrade_Text.Text = "M"
                Case "D"
                    grade_Score = sub_Grade >= 500 < 520
                    form_Cert.TF_usrGrade_Text.Text = "D"
            End Select
    end select
```

I have 4 course levels, case 1,2... and within them I need to distinguish what grade a user has entered, how can I have two select case statements for this?

Comment: What is the line `grade_Score = sub_Grade >= 420 < 460` intended to do?

Comment: See the comment @AndrewMorton above - the lines like the one in his comment will only ever return a boolean result - True or False, which, if you have option strict turned off, will be evaluated as 1 or 0. What value is being returned from the combo box? Is it the Grade ("U","P" etc) or a numerical value? At the moment the code doesn't look like it will produce a useful value for `grade_Score`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can nest Select statements within Select statements like this:

```
Select Case form_Login.FF_CorLev_CMB.SelectedIndex
       Case 1
           Select Case SomeParameterHereRegardingTheGrade
                  Case "U"
                      grade_Score = sub_Grade < 420
                      MsgBox("Not enough points")
                  Case "P"
                      grade_Score = sub_Grade >= 420 < 460
                      form_Cert.TF_usrGrade_Text.Text = "P"
                  Case "M"
                      grade_Score = sub_Grade > 460 < 500
                      form_Cert.TF_usrGrade_Text.Text = "M"
                  Case "D"
                       grade_Score = sub_Grade >= 500 < 520
                       form_Cert.TF_usrGrade_Text.Text = "D"
             End Select
         Case 2
           Select Case SomeParameterHereRegardingTheGrade
                  Case "U"
                      grade_Score = sub_Grade < 420
                      MsgBox("Not enough points")
                  Case "P"
                      grade_Score = sub_Grade >= 420 < 460
                      form_Cert.TF_usrGrade_Text.Text = "P"
                  Case "M"
                      grade_Score = sub_Grade > 460 < 500
                      form_Cert.TF_usrGrade_Text.Text = "M"
                  Case "D"
                      grade_Score = sub_Grade >= 500 < 520
                      form_Cert.TF_usrGrade_Text.Text = "D"
               End Select           
     End select
```

Comment: I don't know what the parameter would be, could I use a text value of the case? As case 1 would be subsidiary so, maybe something like corLev.text = "" just can't figure that bit out either

Comment: Well, it all depends on how your application is built. As it stands right now it kind of assumes that you have something to compare to "U","P","M","D". If there isn't anything to compare it to, the Select statement is useless.

Comment: I have a loop above that goes through all combo box and checks what grade is entered, could that work?

Comment: Could do the trick, yes. Make a variable like "Dim grade As String" and then have the Select statment be something like "Select Case grade" and use that, should work.